# Newest/latest/last version of a product

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Are all the sentences below correct? Do they mean exactly the same?

- You can download the **latest version** of X from this link.
- You can download the **last version** of X from this link.
- You can download the **newest version** of X from this link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree with "cornbread ninja"; ***latest*** and ***newest*** mean the same thing.  However, ***last*** might refer to a previous version, but it might also refer to the ***final*** version of some product.  It really depends on the context.

Comment: +1 for "last" possibly implying "final."  However, I suggest "immediately preceding" rather than "a previous"   (I would even accept "the previous" over "a previous").

Answer (score 7):

*Latest* and *newest* are synonymous; *last* implies that there is a newer version available than the one available at the link.  Grammatically speaking, they are all correct but carry two meanings among them.